# How to avoid [object Object] rendering in a template literal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a const that is equal to a function and i'm trying to render the result in a template literal, see following code

```
<p className="">{`Test here ${this.props.bmiClass} `}</p>
const bmiClass = this.getBmi(calcBmi);
```

getBmi:

```
  function getBmi(bmi) {
    if (bmi < 18.5) {
      return (
        <p>
          <Logo />
          Maigre
        </p>
      );
    }
    if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 24.9) {
      return <p>Normal</p>;
    }
    if (bmi >= 25 && bmi < 29.9) {
      return <p>Surpoids</p>;
    }
    if (bmi >= 30) {
      return <p>Obèse</p>;
    }
  }
```

However it's passing as [object Object] when i render on my page.
I have tried JSON.stringify() toString() String(), but doesn't seem to work.

Help would be very much appreciated

Comment: `JSON.stringify` might not work as expected but at least show you what's actually stored in `bmiClass`; anyway, we need to see `getBmi()` (also React works like this: `<p className="">Test here {this.props.bmiClass}</p>`)

Comment: Please provide code with which we can reproduce the problem. We have no clue what `getBmi` returns, how that constant ended up in your state, in which order this is executed, ...etc.

Comment: Hi, here is the full code for getBmi()
  `getBmi = (bmi) => {
    if(bmi < 18.5) {
        return <p><Logo/>Maigre</p>;
        
    }
    if(bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 24.9) {
        return <p>Normal</p>;
    }
    if(bmi >= 25 && bmi < 29.9) {
      return <p>Surpoids</p>;
    }
    if(bmi >= 30) {
      return <p>Obèse</p>;
        
    }
  }`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use JSX as a variable in template literal. This is why you see `[object Object]`. Instead, you can use it like that:

```
<p className="">Test here {this.props.bmiClass}</p>
```

You are using the JSX regularly here, but you want to insert another piece of JSX as a variable so you use `{}` to make this. By the way, this will make a `p` inside another `p`. So, probably you want to think another way of rendering your data. But, your main problem is not that.

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot for your quick reply, much appreciated